# Calculating a triple integral and defining boundaries

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

So I have to solve the following integral:

$$\iiint_G\,dV,$$

where G is defined as:

$$x^2+y^2-z^2 \geq 6R^2,\; x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 12R^2,\;z \geq 0.$$

So since I have a sphere I am thinking of using spherical coordinates:

\begin{align*}
x&=r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\
y&=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z&=r\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}

So since the graph is halved, I presume $\theta\in[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3}]$ at first look, not involving structure yet. $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$

And for $r$ I got:
$$\left[\frac{\sqrt6R}{\cos(2\theta)},2\sqrt3R\right] \;.$$

Is this the right way I took, or did I make any mistakes? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that this is easier in cyllindrical coordinates

Comment: Why $\frac {\pi}{4}$ as a limit for $\theta$?

Comment: @DougM my mistake when drawing a sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align*}
x&=r\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\
y&=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z&=r\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}$

$x^2+ y^2 - z^2  =r^2 (\cos^2\theta -\sin^2\theta) \ge 6R^2\\
r \ge \frac {R\sqrt 6}{\sqrt {\cos 2\theta}}$

and

$  12R^2\ge r^2 \ge \frac {6R^2}{2\cos\theta}\\
\cos 2\theta \ge \frac 12\\
\theta \le \frac {\pi}{6}$

$z = 0$ coresponds to $\theta = 0$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac \pi6}\int_\frac {R\sqrt6}{\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}}^{R\sqrt 12} r\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi$